# Convert each column of a record into separate record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a record:

```
DECLARE @Tbl AS TABLE(Col1 VARCHAR(10), Col2 VARCHAR(10), Col3 VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @Tbl 
VALUES('Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3')

-- Source Record
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM @Tbl
```

Result: Val1       Val2       Val3

I want result of each column as separate two column records like first column will become the title of source column and second column should be the value of source column like the result of below query in which I have achieved the result by `UNION ALL` :

```
--Query for Target Result
SELECT 'Col1' AttributeTitle, CONVERT(VARCHAR, Col1) AttributeValue FROM @Tbl
UNION ALL SELECT 'Col2' AttributeTitle, CONVERT(VARCHAR, Col2) AttributeValue FROM @Tbl
UNION ALL SELECT 'Col3' AttributeTitle, CONVERT(VARCHAR, Col3) AttributeValue FROM @Tbl
```

Problem in this query is I have to explicitly define the columns, is there any way that it should dynamically get the columns names and their values?

Comment: There's no easy way.  You could use the schema views to write dynamic sql.  Or maybe an UNPIVOT.

Comment: Would you please let me know how I could use schema views to write dynamic SQL for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but you still need to know the names of the columns.

```
SELECT ColumnName, ValueName 
FROM (SELECT * FROM @Tbl) AS Data
UNPIVOT
(   ValueName
    FOR ColumnName IN (Col1, Col2, Col3)
) AS PivottedOutput
```

Comment: Thanks David, but my question was:
"it should dynamically get the columns names and their values?"

Comment: Is this always a temporary table or is it a real table?

Comment: It could be both real table as well as variable of User Defined Table Type.

Answer (score 1):

I like the `apply` method for unpivoting in SQL Server:

```
select v.*
from @tbl t cross apply
     (values ('col1', col1),
             ('col2', col2),
             ('col3', col3)
     ) v(AttributeTitle, AttributeValue);
```

This simplifies the query but it does not directly answer the question.

If you want a variable number of columns, then you are going to have to use dynamic SQL.  This is a bit cumbersome on a real table.  However, with a table variable or a temporary table, you have the additional issue of scoping rules -- the name of the table will not be in scope when you execute the statement.

Comment: Would you please let me know how I could write dynamic SQL for this purpose?